# Handle plugins with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have been making a CMS as a project for a little while now, and am currently working on the plugin management section.  Instead of building my own repository & update manager, I've been toying with the idea to use composer instead.  The issue is I want the admins on the site to be able to add/remove plugins at will.

So I was thinking, how bad of an idea would it be to build a front-end which runs composer?  Composer is just PHP after all, it's meant to be run on production environments (granted with a composer.lock file though), and it'd resolve all of my repository, update, and dependency needs.

I knocked out a quick test script, I built and passed in a custom configuration file (instead of composer.json, the installed plugins list is stored in the database), and everything seems to be working fine.  But I can't shake the feeling of this being a bad idea.

Does anyone have experience with this, and whether or not it is a good or bad idea?

Comment: I'd oppose the thought that Composer is meant to be run *on production environments*. First of all, it has only seen an alpha stability release so far. Then, running it *on the production machine* requires this machine to have a whole bunch of settings that are undesirable for a production machine, like having development tools installed, and having nearly free access to the web. I suggest running Composer *for* production, but not *on production machines*. Run it on a separate machine, then put the result online.

Comment: @Sven I both agree and disagree. It's risky but no more risky than writing your own plugin manager, even how much effort has been put into Composer already, and from the best devs in the PHP world. Would be worth using for personal projects, then submitting bugs if there are any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Composer as an embedded dependency manager with a front end is actually a very valid use case for it.  Here are some links with information, as well as a project meant specifically to help with embedding composer into an application.

https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-embedded-composer
https://sculpin.io/documentation/embedded-composer
http://srcmvn.com/blog/2013/05/23/symfony-live-2013-portland-embedded-composer